# C# Nested Type Aliases - Cannot Resolve Symbol

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, using, type-alias

Why doesn't this compile in Unity 2018 C#?

```
namespace MyNS
{
    using FooTable = Dictionary<int, float[]>;
    using BarTable = Dictionary<int, FooTable>;
}
```

Likewise, if I omit the namespace:

```
using FooTable = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, float[]>;
using BarTable = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, FooTable>;
```

I get the same compiler error.

(Frankly I don't know why the Dictionary qualifiers are optional inside the namespace, yet mandatory outside!)

The compiler error is for the last symbol in the `using BarTable...` line: "Cannot resolve symbol `FooTable`".

Is it not possible to nest type aliases in this way?

Comment: " I don't know why the Dictionary qualifiers are optional inside the namespace, yet mandatory outside" - because **inside** the `namespace` statement the compiler knows that at-least the "outside" namespaces are imported, whereas "outside" it does not.

Comment: @Dai ah, so what happens if I declare two namespaces in the same file? Will both namespaces get the same set of imported namespaces? Does make me wonder why the top-level `using` declarations aren't *inside* the namespace though...

Comment: correct, you can have multiple `namespace` blocks in the same `*.cs` file - and yes inside they’ll both “inherit” the same imported “outer” namespaces but they don’t share “inner” imported namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just not allowed by the compiler:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#remarks

> Create a using alias directive to make it easier to qualify an
> identifier to a namespace or type. In any using directive, the
> fully-qualified namespace or type must be used regardless of the using
> directives that come before it. No using alias can be used in the
> declaration of a using directive. For example, the following generates
> a compiler error:

```
using s = System.Text;
using s.RegularExpressions; // Generates a compiler error.
```

Comment: So is there a way to create nested type aliases? What if I end up with something hierarchical with many types, like `Dictionary<Foo, Dictionary<Bar, Dictionary<Baz, Dictionary<Fuz, int>>>>`? Am I resigned to copy/pasting each subtype everywhere? I'm looking for something like the `using` or `typedef` keywords in C++.